# Installing apk file in Honey Comb Emulator in my mac

Tags: android, apk

I was trying to install apk file in y HoneyComb emulator using the adb install myfile.apk
But in the terminal i got an error saying that...binary files cannot be installed. I am using Mac (Snow Leopard).
Can any one tell me how to install the file in my emulator...?

```
users-mac-pro:tools user$ ./adb install MyApp.apk 
-bash: ./adb: cannot execute binary file
```

---

**Edit:**

**A:**
*Use MAC specific Android SDK*

Thanks in advance

Happy Coding

Comment: Is it your own app? You don't need to manually install your own apps on the emulator, just click "Launch" in Eclipse. Otherwise, the APK-package might be corrupted. Can you check the MD5 sum with the original source?

Comment: Did the actual error say "...binary files cannot be installed"? Give us the error message and any other details you have.

Comment: thanks for your response ...I have included the lines from the terminal along with my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having the SDK for linux in my mac...it was running smooth for the emulator but found difficulties in installing apk files using `adb install command`...but now when I have the SDK for Mac,I can execute my apk file...

thanks all..for your time.

Answer (score 1):

adb in your /platform-tools directory doesn't have an x bit set (chmod +x adb to fix) or is otherwise not executable, in which case running something like 'bash adb ' should get you going.

This is assuming you're in your platform-tools directory.  If not, switch to platform-tools and try again.

Comment: I was having the SDK for linux in my mac...it was running smooth for the emulator...but now when I have the SDK for Mac,I can execute my apk file...thanks for ur answer...

Comment: And thanks for accepting your own instead of my offer of help you ingrate.

Comment: I have selected my answer since it was precisely the issues and I got it solved by the given solution, if any one looking for similar issues can use it, Any way it wont increase my reputation if I mark my own answer...! I just want to help who need it...but since you have spent these much time for me I have given 'a up' for your response..thanks once again for the response